# How to assign equal deployments across multiple nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

This seems like it should be simple enough, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

We have three labeled nodes:

`thalia0`
`thalia1`
`thalia2`

and a Deployment spec, named `mm-sa`.

I would simply like to set number of replicas of `mm-sa` to 48 and have the scheduler assign 16 pods to each node.

The closest I could find to this, was here, but it looks like this is not yet avaialble: [Node affinity for even spread of pods across multiple availability zones](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68981). I also found this, [why-kubernetes-scheduler-ignores-nodeaffinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035421/why-kubernetes-scheduler-ignores-nodeaffinity), but it says that "According to the documentation, nodeAffinity must exist for each node that can be used for a scheduled pod and the node having the biggest weight sum is chosen."

This seems like such a simple use-case, but I cannot figure out how to achieve it without using a naïve approach, as in defining 3-different Deployments named `mm-sa1`, ... `mm-sa3` and using a `nodeSelector` to assign each accordingly. (NB: I am currently using a `nodeSelector` to assign 16-replicas of `mm-sa` on a single node).

Comment: The scheduler by default should spread the pods across the nodes; do you have a specific requirement that it be _exactly_ 1/3 on each node, or do you just not want everything concentrated on a single node?

Comment: Each of the 3 nodes are configured identically with RAM and CPU, so the 16-pods per node is an optimal config determined through testing. Thus, the 1/3 on each node is an ideal.

Comment: What happens if you just set `replicas: 48` and deploy it, without specifically trying to influence the placement?

Comment: Good question. There are other nodes that we wouldn't want the pods to run on, but since we have the `imagePullPolicy` set to `Never` for the Deployment spec (all required docker images are on the specific nodes), I assume the scheduler would only assign the pods to the nodes with the particular images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes will automatically spread the pods in a replication controller or service across nodes in a single-zone cluster. So @David Maze's solution should apply if there are no other nodes. However since you mentioned that you have other nodes that you do not want to schedule on, I would recommend using the *nodeSelector*. By using *nodeSelector*, as long as the node has the same key-value pair in the YAML, the pod will be able to schedule on the node.

You can read more about *nodeSelector* here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector

Comment: I AM using a `nodeSelector` (see edited post above)... however, that does not work for my use case, since I want to distribute the pods across multiple nodes. Is there a way to force a label across mutiple nodes?

Comment: I believe if you provide the same label to the 3 nodes you want to deploy to,  the scheduler should deploy the pods evenly.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know you could do that. i just tested it and it certainly allows labels to span across multiple nodes. Thanks!